# Algorithm for computing residues of Galois conjugates of an integer in a prime-power cyclotomic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Let $l$ be an odd prime and let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{l^n})$. Suppose $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{l^n}]$. Let $\mathfrak{p}\mid p$ be a split prime (so in particular $p\equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ l^n)$) so that $\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{p} \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.  Let $G=Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$. Let $(a,b)$ denote the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. For $g\in G$ define $\iota(g)=v_{\mathfrak{p}}(x^g,y^g)$ and $(x(g),y(g))=(x^g,y^g)p^{-\iota(g)}$. Then $x(g),y(g)$ are $\mathbb{p}-$integral and at most one of them is divisible  by $\mathfrak{p}$. What I would like to know is if there is an algorithm that allows you to compute a list of possible residues of the $(x(g),y(g))$ from the residues of $(x(1),y(1))$ and a choice of $\zeta_{l^n} \ (\text{mod} \ \mathfrak{p})$.

Even if we begin with the hypothesis that $\mathfrak{p} \nmid x^g$ for all $g \in G$, i.e. that $(N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(x),p)=1$ so that $(x(g),y(g))=(x^g,y^g)$, the knowledge of the residue of $x(1)$ is probably not enough to find the residues of the conjugates. But maybe there is a way to shorten the list of possible residues. Any insight or reference recs would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you are thinking to. What do you mean with "the greatest common divisor"? If $a,b\in O_L$ then $(a,b)$ is an ideal and it doesn't have to be principal. The notation $(x(g),y(g))=(x^g,y^g)p^{-\iota(g)}$ is forbidden. What do you mean with the residues of $x(1),y(1)$.

Comment: Yes $(a,b)$ is the largest ideal containing the principal ideals $(a)$ and $(b)$ so no it doesn't have to be principal but if $\mathfrak{p}$ is split, then $p$ is a uniformizer so $(x(g),y(g))$ as defined is a pair of elements not necessarily in $\mathcal{O}_L$ but in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}}$. I'm saying suppose we know the residue of $x(1) \ (\text{mod} \mathfrak{p})$, do we know anything about the residues of $x(g) \ (\text{mod} \ \mathfrak{p})$ ?

Comment: Please no $x(g)$. You meant $\iota = \min v_\mathfrak{p}(a),v_\mathfrak{p}(b)$ and $g(x) p^{-\iota}$, right? If $g$ sends $\mathfrak{p}$ to itself (the decomposition subgroup) then it is an automorphism of $O_\mathfrak{p}$ giving an automorphism $h$ of $O_\mathfrak{p}/(p)$ so that $g(x) p^{-\iota}=h(xp^{-\iota})\bmod p O_\mathfrak{p}$. If $g$ is not in the decomposion group then we can't say much as shown with $y=x=2+i, O_\mathfrak{p}=\Bbb{Z}[i]_{(2+i)},p=5,
x p^{-\iota}=\frac1{2-i}, g(x)=2-i,g(x) p^{-\iota}=\frac1{2+i}$.